# How to convert .ts file into good quality mp4 programmatically?

Tags: video, html5-video, webm

My web service fetches chunks of .ts files from an m3u8 file and create a single .ts file.Now I want to play this file on web.For that I use 'avconv' utility in Ubuntu via

> avconv -i source.ts -acodec copy -vcodec copy destination.mp4

However I dont get a good 'playable' mp4 everytime.Sometimes its just audio and video stucks in between. It also shows wrong duration label.

Is there any good way to convert .ts into mp4 or BETTER into webm format.My requirement is to play on web ...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure your input file is OK, because GIGO (garbage in, garbage out).

`HLS` can use adaptive streaming so check if your `m3u8` is a variant playlist. Eg:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1280000
http://example.com/low.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=2560000
http://example.com/mid.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=7680000
http://example.com/hi.m3u8
```

This is necessary because the stream might switch to a different quality based on your network conditions. If the available bandwidth is low enough it can select an audio-only stream, if available.

If it's the case, choose the sub-playlist with the maximum bitrate you can fetch and use it directly as the source of your `ts` segments.

Regarding the transcoding part I suggest you try the same command with [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html). Grab the latest `git` version. You can either compile it yourself (recommended) or grab a package/static build.

If copying the encoding still doesn't work you could try re-encoding the file (eg: `-c:v x264 -c:a libfdk_aac`).

For `WebM` you can do:

```
ffmpeg -i input.ts -c:v libvpx -c:a libvorbis output.webm
```

for `VP8`/`Vorbis` or:

```
ffmpeg -i input.ts -c:v libvpx-vp9 -c:a opus output.webm
```

for `VP9`/`Opus`

This is the most basic example, you should set the encoding parameters instead of using the default values. Check the [documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#libvpx).

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP8

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP9

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264

Comment: Thanks @aergistal !!  installing ffmpeg did work for both mp4 and webm .. However I am considering mp4 as webm encoding takes hell of a time !

Comment: @AnkitDhanna You should try with `VP8`, it's faster. And you can tune the parameters as shown in the guide to achieve a better speed. Even `H.264` in `MP4` can take a while with a slower profile (better compression).

Comment: Thanks... I will look into it